# Why am I receiving a "no coercion operator is defined" error from my FirstOrDefaultAsync method?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I am trying to use `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` to return query results into a variable, but when I call the method, I get the error message `No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Decimal' and 'System.Boolean'`. Here is my code:

```cs
public async Task<ResponseMessages> Handle(Command command, CancellationToken token)
{
     var planogramDetails = await _fastStockContext.BinPlanogram.FirstOrDefaultAsync(g => g.PlanogramId == command.PlanogramId);
```

This is the relevant part of my `Context` class:

```cs
public DbSet<PlanogramDetails> BinPlanogram { get; set; }
```

And this is the model class referred to in the code:

```cs
public class PlanogramDetails
{
    public long PlanogramId { get; set; }
    public string PlanogramName { get; set; }
    public bool IsCustomerManaged { get; set; }
    public int ContainerTypeId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string OwnerBu { get; set; }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How is the table defined? Is `IsCustomerManaged` defined as anything other than `BIT`? What RDBMS are you using? Oracle doesn't have an actual boolean type like SQL Server's `BIT`, and `NUMBER(1)` is often used instead.

Comment: I am using Oracle, and now I see that the type is in fact `NUMBER(1)`. I am now assuming that the problem comes from the fact that in my model class it is a `bool` and in Oracle it is `NUMBER`?

Comment: Do you have the authority to change any of the two?

Comment: Yes. Depending on whether you're using Oracle.DataAccess or Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, it gets mapped differently. One will map any `NUMBER` to `decimal` no matter the precision, and the other will map `NUMBER` with various precision and 0 scale to `byte`, `short`, `int`, or `long` where the precision fits all possible values within that type, or `decimal` if it exceeds the maximum digits of `long`. Either way, though, you may not be able to get a direct mapping to `bool`.

Comment: @Fildor, no I do not, so right now I am just trying to see if a conversion would be possible?

Comment: @madreflection, I am using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

Comment: Hm. I thought that one mapped `NUMBER(1)` to `byte` rather than `decimal`. It's been a while since I ran the tests and I don't use Oracle except for occasional comparative purposes, so clearly it's been too long to remember correctly.

Comment: If you don't have the ability to change the database, that's understandable and quite common, but surely you need to be able to change the entity class. There's no way it's worked before, so you must have the latitude to change it from `bool` to `decimal`. It's just broken otherwise. You can compare it `!= 0m` for its boolean state.

Comment: @madreflection The database no, but the entity class yes. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Mint: Fildor asked *"Do you have the authority to change any of the two?"* and you replied *"no I do not"*, so you had previously indicated otherwise and that's why I phrased it the way I did.